# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating')

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview, build-tools

I am getting these two error messages when trying to compile:

```
/Users/dericw/coding/myApplication/lfdate/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/dericw/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Android Studio then opens up `v23/values-23.xml` with this style:

```
    <style name="CardView" parent="Base.CardView">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating</item>
    </style>
```

But I don't have that defined anywhere in my app. It is a generated file that is giving me the error. I am pretty stumped on how to fix this issue? Has anyone every encountered this before? How do I fix this?

**Project Build File**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**App Build File**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 200
        versionName "1.7.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
    compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.+'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.+'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.+'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.+'
    compile 'com.hudomju:swipe-to-dismiss-undo:1.+'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: linked cordova / ionic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595119/ionic-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-cardbackgroundcolo/36603653#36603653

Answer (score 52, accepted):

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+' needs V-23

Change the facebook version SDK to 4.8.0 then it won't use that resource file. Then your code will be up & running/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This solved my issue! Wish they would tell us which libraries are using the support library. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, pls, where do you specify the SDK to 4.8.0. 
This is the entry I have in the config.xml:
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.0">

Comment: Jesus, how are we supposed to guess this? Thanks for this useful answer.

Answer (score 32):

I also had this issue. I solved by forcing an older version of the card view library as the issue is with that.

```
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
    force = true
}
```

The issue was with 23.2.1 of card view, the Facebook SDK uses this library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The other solutions created other issues; except this one, it worked without complications.

Comment: where do I find this? I don't know where to force the card view library version. Thanks!

Comment: @weilah its in the dependencies block of your modules build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the "cordova-plugin-facebook4" plugin, please remove the plugin from your project and pull it again (the latest version), then add it back to your project.

At the same time, please check the xml file, which is locate at `yourCordovaProject/plugin/cordova-plugin-facebook4/plugin.xml` around line No. 64, it must be `4.8.+` :

`<framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.+"/>`

Answer (score 0):

1. For a **temporary fix** I solved my issue changing the project.properties:

> vi platforms/android/project.properties
>
> and changed from target=android-22 to target=android-23

2. For a **permanent fix** you just need to update the android platform:

> cordova platform update android --save

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap Build users, try this. It worked for me.

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#aff9a08a86cc6c6a18019f7adc2896ddf97c11cd" source="git" >
```

Answer (score 0):

my system already had 23 installed. from project panel, Application -> Open module setting (F4) -> application -> Properties tab. I had Compile Sdk Version Android 5.50 (lollipop). So I changed to API 23+ and it worked.
So I checked Application build.gradle changed 
from     compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
to
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

so I"m guessing you can simply change compoileSdkVersion to your buildTollVersion.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it removing the plugin:

```
 cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4
```

And installing it again from this commit:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4\#aff9a08a86cc6c6a18019f7adc2896ddf97c11cd --save --variable APP_ID="YOUR_FB_APP_ID" --variable APP_NAME="YOUR_FB_APP_NAME"`