# Re-using Gdx-Facebook Access token from other classes

Tags: facebook, libgdx

Lets say I sign in from class **`Login`**, using `gdxFacebook = GDXFacebookSystem.install(config);` and `gdxFacebook.signIn`. I can then call `GDXFacebookGraphRequest request = new GDXFacebookGraphRequest().setNode("me").useCurrentAccessToken();`  without any issues.

However, when I try to use `GDXFacebookGraphRequest request = new GDXFacebookGraphRequest().setNode("me/invitable_friends").useCurrentAccessToken();` from class **`FriendList`** I get an error. I've tried with and without installing facebook again. Do I need to pass `gdxFacebook` from class **`Login`** in order to use the access token? or is there a better way?

*Error message:*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 69865
              Process: com.scene2d.tut.android, PID: 16786
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.core.GDXFacebook.newGraphRequest(de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.core.GDXFacebookGraphRequest, de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.core.GDXFacebookCallback)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You need the gdxFacebook returned from GDXFacebookSystem.install(config); for each request.

Comment: @TomGrill Games So I need to pass the gdxFacebook from my login-class to any other class that needs it? Or can I just run the install again? When I try just installing it again (not passing it from login-class) I get `Graph Reqest: Error. Something went wrong with the access token.`

Comment: Either pass the variable or use GDXFacebookSystem.getFacebook(); after you have installed it.

Comment: Ah, didnt know that existed. Awesome!

Comment: I added it to the Wiki for later vistors.

Comment: Yeah I need to update :) Dont have it. Such an awesome extension btw!

Comment: @TomGrillGames Is the new version using Facebook SDK 4.+? Causing this issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963144/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-cardbackgroundcolor-with-val