# What is meaning for -- (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating')

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a problem while download a project from github.
Error is as:

F:\Tikam\Sample Project\Advance Design Project\ActivitySceneTransitionBasic\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\cardview-v7\23.3.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').
Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:processDebugResources'.

```
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Android Development\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

my v23\values-v23.xml file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CardView" parent="Base.CardView">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I don't see `--` in your question

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963144/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-cardbackgroundcolor-with-val

Comment: @cricket_007 Above post  is  related to  facebook sdk version problem. And my question is not for particular facebook it is general problem question

Comment: Read the second answer there, please. It's not directly Facebook related

Comment: Please show your build.gradle file